# Azure functions deploying fail from VS Code

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I am trying to deploy my azure function (python) from VS code and it's giving the below error.

I was able to debug my code in my local machine without any error, and I am not understanding why deployment is failing.

[image: 11:55:51 PM nhtsacleanse: Detecting platforms... 11:55:51 PM nhtsacleanse: Error: Oops... An unexpected error has occurred. 11:55:53 PM nhtsacleanse: /opt/Kudu/Scripts/starter.sh oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform python --platform-version 3.7 -p packagedir=.python_packages/lib/site-packages 11:55:57 PM nhtsacleanse: Deployment failed.]

[image]

Created azure function app in azure portal

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sometimes deploy function by extension may show unexpected error. Could you please have a try with create the function app first on azure portal and then use this command `func azure functionapp publish <functionAppName> --build remote` in VS code to deploy your function from local to azure.

Answer (score 7):

This was the shortest path to a solution for me. This reference:

> Key                   Sample value
> AzureWebJobsStorage   DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=...
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#azurewebjobsstorage

Lead me to inspecting my azure function app configuration:

[image]

And seeing that the AzureWebJobsStorage was missing.

I had already created a storage account, when I tried to deploy my function previously, and evidently, the deployment step created the storage account for me, but failed to add that storage account to the function app configuration.

I retrieved the connection string from:

> storage account -> access keys -> connection string

and used the value in the source value of the AzureWebJobsStoage configuration setting.

After adding that configuration, I was able to then run the following command from Visual Studio Code, with the Azure Function App workspace open:

> func azure functionapp publish Text-To-Image --build remote

And received a confirmation stating:

> Deployment successful.
> Remote build succeeded!

Answer (score 5):

If you are getting this issue, it means your storage account connection string is different from a function app connection string.

To confirm, you can check function app configuration:

[image]

and also check the storage account connection string:

[image]

One way is just add the same connection string of storage account into the function app or just create the new function app inside this storage.

Note: This error comes when we accidentally delete the storage account but the function app is still using the connection string of that storage account.

Answer (score 4):

According to my experience, deploy function by clicking the button in VS code sometimes may occur unexpected error message. You can deploy your function by using command `func azure functionapp publish <functionAppName> --build remote` instead.

Before run the command in your VS code, you need to create a function app first on azure portal. Please choose python 3.7 like below screenshot show when you create the function app on portal(to avoid version issue) because it seems your local python function is 3.7. Then run the command in "Terminal" window of your VS code to deploy the code from local to azure. I usually use this deployment method and always works fine.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I tried to deploy using the command,but this is giving a different error.

'fleetbadrecordcleanse' app is missing AzureWebJobsStorage app setting. That setting is required for publishing consumption linux apps.

Comment: Here is my local.settings.json 
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=***;AccountKey=*****;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "MyStorageConnectionAppSetting": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=****;AccountKey=****;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python"
  }
}

Comment: Thanks @Hury Shen, any idea about this error.

Comment: @Rahul It seems your function app on azure missing "AzureWebJobsStorage", could you please check if the function app you created has "AzureWebJobsStorage" like this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZ1kX.png) ?

Comment: Yes @Hury Shen,I have AzureWebJobsStorge in the app configuration

Comment: @Rahul The screenshot you provided shows `AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType` but not `AzureWebJobsStorge` ?

Comment: @Rahul May I know how did you create the function app on portal ?

Comment: Hi @Hury Shen,sorry for the late response
 1. I created function app in azure portal (please see the screenshot that i added to the post).
2. I tried to deploy the function from VS code using func azure functionapp publish nhtsacleanup --build remote
 
I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Could you please have a try with add a key-value `AzureWebJobsStorge:yourStorageConnectionString` in application settings of your function app ?

Comment: Thanks @Hury Shen,I tried and it fixed my error, now I am getting a different error.       
                                          
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67655151/azure-function-error-app-does-not-support-remote-build-as-it-was-created-before/67655423?noredirect=1#comment119586711_67655423

Comment: "Before run the command in your VS code, you need to create a function app first on azure portal." Thank you for this, now where was this said in the MSFT docs.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was I had to create a master branch, then the command tools worked. Also after that, the VS Code tools worked. Only way I figured this out was looking at the error output of the CLI publish command.