# Azure function error: app does not support remote build as it was created before August 1st, 2019

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-functions-core-tools

I am trying to deploy my azure function with VS code using func azure functionapp publish nhtsa --build remote and I am getting below error.

Remote build is a new feature added to function apps.
Your function app does not support remote build as it was created before August 1st, 2019.
Please use '--build local' or '--build-native-deps'.
For more information, please visit https://aka.ms/remotebuild

I thought it's because of the storage account access -tier and access level, so I change my storage account tier to **cool** and container access to **public**, and I deploy the function again, and I'm still getting the error.

Any idea how I can resolve this issue.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the error specified, it is not supported for function app created before August 1, 2019 (see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-technologies#remote-build)):

> If you're having issues with remote build, it might be because your app was created before the feature was made available (August 1, 2019). Try creating a new function app, or running `az functionapp update -g <RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME> -n <APP_NAME>` to update your function app. This command might take two tries to succeed.

Comment: Thanks, @Thomas, I updated my function app using this cmd az functionapp update -g <RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME> -n <APP_NAME> and I deployed it again,and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: did you try to update multiple times as suggested in the documentation ?

Comment: Yes @Thomas , i tried multiple times and it's returning some JSON content when i try to update app.
I create a new function app in portal and I deploy it again, and that didn't work too.

Comment: do I have to change anything in host.json  ???
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  }
}

Comment: I dont think so, could you past your build steps ? how it is configured ?

Comment: Is it linux, windows ? for linux you need these two app settings: `ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD=true`, `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true`. It also needs to be zip deploy, not run from package.

Comment: Yes it is Iinux,, I added two app settings (added screenshot to post) and also changed the function app runtime version to 2, and still it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue the solution was to fix the "defaultAction"
It should be "Allow"